# Payment not send by Bridge server

Tags: bridge-server

I am facing an issue regarding the bridge server.

I am trying to send payment using bridge server which is installed locally with version "**bridge-v0.0.30-linux-amd64**". And uses same program and bridge.cfg file from [bridge documentation](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/anchor/2-bridge-server.html). But while running Java program I got the following error message:

```
{   
    "code": "missing_parameter",   
    "message": "Required parameter is missing.",   
    "data": {   
        "name": "amount"   
    } 
}
```

How to get proper output? Is anything is missing from `.cfg` file?

Comment: Can you post raw request you're sending to the bridge server?

Answer (score 1):

This information is not enough. What code are your trying to execute? Where is the stack trace of the error?

As I understand from the error description, you are trying to send some funds, but request parameters are invalid (specifically, parameter `amount` is missing).

Check this example of properly formed request:

```
var request = require('request');

request.post({
  url: 'http://localhost:8001/payment',
  form: {
    amount: '1',
    asset_code: 'USD',
    asset_issuer: 'GAIUIQNMSXTTR4TGZETSQCGBTIF32G2L5P4AML4LFTMTHKM44UHIN6XQ',
    destination: 'GCFXHS4GXL6BVUCXBWXGTITROWLVYXQKQLF4YH5O5JT3YZXCYPAFBJZB',
    source: 'SAV75E2NK7Q5JZZLBBBNUPCIAKABN64HNHMDLD62SZWM6EBJ4R7CUNTZ'
  }
}, function(error, response, body) {
  if (error || response.statusCode !== 200) {
    console.error('ERROR!', error || body);
  }
  else {
    console.log('SUCCESS!', body);
  }
});
```